# How to install IBM Netezza OLEDB Provider on Microsoft SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, ssis, oledb, netezza

I have a database server running Microsoft SQL Server 2012 SP4 where I am trying to run SSIS packages as jobs through the SQL Server Agent that connect to our IBM netezza server, but my SQL Server does not have the requisite provider (IBM Netezza OLEDB) to interface with Netezza. Our DBAs have told me to figure it out myself, which is normally not an issue, but resources online seem to be *very* thin on this subject; has anyone dealt with this before or know of a resource that would instruct a noob like me how to go about installing the provider?

Comment: need to sign up:  https://www.ibm.com/support/fixcentral/swg/selectFixes?parent=ibm%7EInformation%20Management&product=ibm/Information%20Management/Netezza%20NPS%20Software%20and%20Clients&release=NPS_7.2.1&platform=Windows&function=all

Answer (score 0):

I don’t know why, but the package containing ODBC,JDBC and OLEDB drivers from IBM can usually only be obtained by raising an IBM support ticket.
Personally I would run an ‘all-but-open-source’ policy On the client software, but I’m not IBM :)